# Creating Lists with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-lists, parameter-passing

I am querying three databases and want to show their columns in three click-able lists. I want the user to select a number of columns from these lists and then on pressing a button,  only the selected columns and the lists/tables that they came from would be passed to a function for processing.

I found some code online that does this with forms. Is there any way to do this without forms? I am used to using JList with java and have little experience with javascript.

.

The code that does something similar to what I am trying to do (with forms) for one list is:

http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial006.html

**EDIT:** I just found out about Javascript ListBoxes. I think I am just going to use them. It seems like using forms is going to inevitable when creating lists.

Comment: Could you provide more details like how you building your your lists and the code that you found. If you building your page dynamically then you dont really need javascript as you could simply submit the page and return the new results. Javascript should only be used to "progressively" enhance you web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is a really simple JavaScript library for doing things like this (and for user interaction in general).

For example, if you want to select the second column of a table and store the cells' data into an array, this simple code would do it (I'm notorious for making mistakes, so correct me if it doesn't):

```
var elements = [];

$('#id_of_your_table tr td:eq(1)').each(function()
{
  elements.push($(this).html());
});
```

Now, `elements` contains the values of the second column of the table.

---

You're talking about plain 'ol HTML `<select>`, I think. Paste this into an HTML document to see what I mean.

```
<select id="my_listbox" multiple="yes" size="6">
  <option>Foo 1</option>
  <option>Foo 2</option>
  <option>Foo 3</option>
  <option>Foo 4</option>
  <option>Foo 5</option>
  <option>Foo 6</option>
</select>
```

To get the selected values, this code should work:

```
var values = [];

$('#my_listbox :selected').each(function(i, selected)
{
  textvalues[i] = $(selected).text();
});
```

---

If your users can't figure out how to check the items, writing your own checkable listbox is *really* easy. Check out my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/2hDVR/2/.

Comment: I am not doing anything with tables. I am going to generate 3 lists that are the column labels and the user selects which columns he wants to use, clicks them all presses a button and then they are all passed to a function that processes them

Comment: How are you making them? Are they just tons of `<div>` tags?

Comment: I havent made the lists yet. I am asking the best way to go about making them. I have used JLists with Java and am hoping javascript would have the identical functionality

Comment: Can you explain how they should look? A table would be ideal if you have three vertical lists, but each situation requires slightly different code.

Comment: I think I am going to use ListBoxes

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. Those are actually plain ol' HTML, so JavaScript isn't even required to make them.

Comment: a list box works technically, but tends to be a pain from a UX POV. Not everyone understands how to multi-select options in a listbox.

Comment: that said...due to limitations of Java frameworks, I have had to render a list of checkboxes on the client side via javascript that, in turn, update a hidden listbox which then get's submitted back to the server. A hack, for sure.

Comment: You could make your own with jQuery and CSS. It's *really* easy. In fact, I'll write a custom really-obvious-that-I-can-check-it example.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't 'make lists'. Lists are HTML. Your JavaScript can render HTML, but I assume you're getting this from the server anyways.

I'd probably do this via HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="column1" />column 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="column2" />column 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" id="columnn" />column n</label></li>
</ul>
```

I'm not sure what you are asking in regards to wanting to do this without a form. Either way you need to pass data back to the server to get the data to render the completed table. That's what forms are for.